# Translating "Hic fortissimus, primus inter pares" into English

Tags: word-request, translation-check, adjective, latin-to-english-translation

I am currently studying Latin in high school (third year), so I do have a mild understanding of how the language works. But I would like to know whether this translation is correct. For various reasons, I can't ask my Latin teacher.

> Hic fortissimus, primus inter pares.

hoping to mean:

> This most powerful (individual), the first amongst equals.

Also, I am looking for an adjective to mean "powerful" as in "with great authority/influential". Would you recommend any other word besides "fortes"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the first part of the sentence, it would be more correct to specify “this most powerful (man)” because “hic” and “fortissimus” are masculine. I have some doubts about the second part of the sentence because “pares” is an adjective and not a noun, but the author could have just left out a word (ellipsis) and implied “equal men” or something, which is pretty close to “equals”. Other than that, it looks good to me!

As for your second question, “potens, potentis” is a third declension adjective that is commonly used in a similar sense as what you described. I find the website [Whitaker’s Words](http://archives.nd.edu/words.html) extremely helpful for finding both the Latin for English words and vice versa.

Good luck with the rest of your translation!

Comment: [*primus inter pares*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primus_inter_pares) is actually an established idiom with its own Wiki page! As for *hic fortissimus*, it seems more like "this [man is the] strongest" to me. +1 for *potens*

Comment: Thank you both very much.
But, @brianpck , could _"Hic potentissimus"_ be understood as _"This [men who is the] most powerful"_? I don't know whether this was apparent or not, but I am trying to translate an English text to Latin, in a more _poetical_ manner ‒ some sort of motto, if you wish.

Comment: @SuperSoldier It certainly could mean that, in a certain context. As a standalone sentence, without further context, I think my interpretation would definitely be more natural.

Comment: @brianpck Could you avoid the ambiguity by writing *Hic fortissimus (vir) est primus inter pares*? Would that be a more natural way of communicating the OP's intention? Or would *et* be a better choice than *est*?

Comment: I guess the question, more generally, is whether Latin has an analog to the English appositive construction that the OP would like to translate.